# How do I print out html text from specific place?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

Current code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import urllib.request as ur

with ur.urlopen(f'https://jobs.siemens.com/jobs?page=1&sortBy=relevance&limit=100') as response:
    html = response.read()
    soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')
    
    for tag in soup.find_all(?):
        print(tag.string)
```

Currently I am trying to get the first Req Id (**234103**) from the site opened with **urlopen**. As you can see there is a ? in the **find_all**, this is because in the site if I inspect element on the Req Id it is inside **span _ngcontent-blo-c163=""></span** . The problem is that I dont know how I can make python search for the text inside that html tag.

How can I make python print out the words inside a html tag, and how can I make it work for this specific one?

Comment: the website you trying to scrap is a SPA and cant be accomplished with  BeautifulSoup, BeautifulSoup is used for smaller tasks and not javascript featured websites.  Use Selenium for SPA website.

Comment: @Karimov Will Scrapy also work?

Comment: Scrapy cannot run javascript code while scraping.